# Javascript - Full Screen Image Code

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/MAaVV/

Above is the JSFiddle for my code. It's some CSS to make an image full screen, and then a simple src change for the image. I want to change image backgrounds every 5 seconds. It's below as well:

```
<STYLE type=text/css>
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

for(var x = 0; x < 2; x++)
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        var imgs = ["http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/aprilia_rsv4_motorcycles-wide.jpg","http://chivethethrottle.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/user-girl-motorcycle-920-3.jpg","clf.jpg"];
        document.getElementById("img").src = imgs[x];
    },5000);
}
</script>

<div id="bg">
  <img id="img" src="http://chivethethrottle.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/user-girl-motorcycle-920-3.jpg?w=919&h=613" alt="" />
</div>
```

Anyone know why it isn't working?

Bonus points for building in a redirect (to another website) after the last image of the slideshow is shown for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var imgs = ["http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/aprilia_rsv4_motorcycles-wide.jpg", "http://chivethethrottle.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/user-girl-motorcycle-920-3.jpg"]; 
var i=0;
setInterval(function () {        
    document.getElementById("img").src = imgs[i];
    if(i==1)
    {
        //alert('test');
        $("#img").click(function(){
            alert('on');
            location.href='http://www.google.com';
        });
    }
    if(i++>=1) i=0;   
}, 5000);
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/MAaVV/6/

Comment: Check the above code, it may not run on `Fiddle` beacuse it uses `iframe`, but runs on a single `html page`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails for two reasons:

1. You set all three (or two in th case of the jsFiddle) timeouts to run at the same time. Your code sets all three to run 5 seconds after the call, but all the calls are made at the same time, so they'll all run 5 seconds later.
2. You use the `x` variable in your timeout function, but it is not defined in the scope for that function. So, in all cases, the image is getting 'undefined' as the src.

To fix this, I'd use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imageIndex = 0;
var imgs = ["http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/aprilia_rsv4_motorcycles-wide.jpg","http://chivethethrottle.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/user-girl-motorcycle-920-3.jpg","clf.jpg"];


setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("img").src = imgs[imageIndex++];
    if(imageIndex >= imgs.length) imageIndex = 0;
    },5000);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MAaVV/5/

EDIT: To make the function do something after all the slides have shown, you might try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imageIndex = 0;
var imgs = ["http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/aprilia_rsv4_motorcycles-wide.jpg","http://chivethethrottle.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/user-girl-motorcycle-920-3.jpg","clf.jpg"];

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("img").src = imgs[imageIndex++];
    if(imageIndex >= imgs.length){
        clearInterval(interval);
        setTimeout(function(){
            // do whatever you want here, after a 5 second pause
        },5000);
},5000);
</script>
```

Comment: I've realized that, that setInterval is built like that. I'm having trouble doing my redirect after the slideshow is finished too, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgs = ["http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/aprilia_rsv4_motorcycles-wide.jpg", "http://chivethethrottle.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/user-girl-motorcycle-920-3.jpg"];   

var currentImage = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        if (currentImage >= imgs.length)
        {
            currentImage = 0;
            window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        }
        else
        {
            currentImage++;
        }

        $("#bg #img").attr("src", imgs[currentImage]);
    }, 5000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MAaVV/2/